# Spring Boot bidirectional ManyToOne constraint

Tags: spring, many-to-one, bidirectional

Here are my 2 entities with a bidirectional ManyToOne relation. I deleted getters and setters to simplify the code.

```js
@Entity
public class City {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 protected int id;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
 protected ZonedDateTime creationDate;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
 protected ZonedDateTime updatedDate;

 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
 @Column(unique = true)
 protected String name;
   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    protected Collection<Spot> spots;
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name", "address", "city_id" }))
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Spot {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 protected int id;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
 protected ZonedDateTime creationDate;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
 protected ZonedDateTime updatedDate;

 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
 protected String name;

 @NotNull
 @NotBlank
 protected String address;

 @NotNull
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
 // @JsonManagedReference
 protected City city;
}
```

[image]

Because of the second constraint, i can't add more spots than the number of cities. IDs allowed for Spot is in the range of <1 to number of cities>.

Here is the error i get :

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDatabase`.`spot`, CONSTRAINT `FKo3x3ohxcttkl2at3yr1xviw1r` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`))
```

Any idea ? thank you

Comment: Your association is unidirectional, not bidirectional. We can't understand what the constraints are from this screenshot. Post the SQL defining these constraints, as text. The post the code causing the exception, and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Now your OneToMany mapping doesn't make any sense. mappedBy = "id" should be mappedBy = "city". Why don't you post your real code?

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you !! That was the mistake ! I thought that i had to map spots in City with the id of the spot object.